# How to make page blank when user access php file directly?

Tags: php, html

So I'm trying to make a theme from my Html file. And using `require('file.php')` where `file.php` is a series of different components of my theme. Now when I access the file directly, I still see the html. How do I make it display a blank page when user accesses the `file.php` directly?

**Explanation**
So let's say I make index.php and I want to include the header file(`header.php`)

When I `require('header.php')`, everything works perfect. Now when I try to access the `header.php`, I can see the html content of it. How to I make this appear blank instead of seeing the `header.php` piece?
Thanks

Comment: if (condition) { die(); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, If you want to execute `header.php` inside the `index.php` or etc. You need to add or `define` a flag in parent files (wherever you want `header.php` to be executed or simply adding in to the common file which is called in all parent files), In **header.php** file you need check the defined flag is set or has some value. If it is not set, then stop execution by using `die();` function.

**In index.php**,

```
<?php $HeaderAllow ='1';  ?>
```

**In header file**,

```
 <?php 
     if($HeaderAllow=='' or !isset($HeaderAllow)){
         die();
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean here. :S Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Updated the comments, please check

Comment: Thanks :) It's easy now :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` here to check and then make page blank in `header.php`.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] == 'header.php') {
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting the include files in a seperate folder and protectinng with `.htaccess` is good idea.

Same issue here.

[deny direct access to a folder and file by htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282124/deny-direct-access-to-a-folder-and-file-by-htaccess)

Comment: - Maz - Denying access is one thing, but what if I just want the page to appear blank?

Comment: then you can do like have some variable set in index file. and check that variable in header.php. If someone accesses this fiel directly variable will not be set so you can simply echo die() or exit. in top part of page. see the above code snippet by @Chinnu R

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put your includes in a directory and deny access to that directory in your .htaccess file