# .htaccess Root Rewrite Without Folders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've spent countless hours searching for similar issues and found the solutions to not work for me. I have an index.php with an '**id**' GET variable to load pages dynamically as mydomain.com/**[idVariableHere]**.

My .htaccess code works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(js|css|images)($|/) - [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, it's not preventing the /js/, /css/, and /images/ folders from being displayed. It's interfering with the last RewriteRule and I have no idea how to get around this.

My goal is to keep the mydomain.com/**[idVariableHere]** look with restriction on these important folders. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 403 default

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Darn. It didn't work... in fact, it has the same exact effect as before. So close! :-(

Comment: What didn't work? What URL did you enter in browser? Test in chrome dev tool and see which URL is causing 404?

Comment: Sorry for being vague! Well, the last RewriteRule worked when I entered mydomain.com/contact which linked to mydomain.com/index.php?id=contact but when I accessed mydomain.com/images, it loaded up index.php with the layout but the body of the page being white. I think it's loading /images.php (which doesn't exist) instead of the /images/ folder.

Comment: Do you have a file called `images.php`? Is there any .htaccess in `/images/`? Are there more rules in above .htaccess?

Comment: images.php does not exist and there is no .htaccess in /images/. This is all located in the root directory. The same issue happens for other folders I've created like /videos/. if I visit mydomain.com/videos/, I expect to see the actual index of /videos/ but instead the last RewriteRule seems to supersede to mydomain.com/index.php?id=videos (/videos.php, which does not exist).

Comment: Forgot to mention, my index.php has, echo  $_GET['id'] . ".php"; to include whatever is entered after mydomain.com/.

Comment: Hmm your PHP code seems to be the problem then. Since there is no rule in .htaccess that is adding `.php` in your URI. Create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then replace `index.php` by `info.php` in above `RewriteRule` and retest.

Comment: I just tried out what you said and had no luck but it did shed some light on the problem a little more. Regardless of it being index.php or info.php (with or without include $_GET['id']), mydomain.com/images/ doesn't even load the initial page (being index.php or info.php). If you try to load any EXISITING folder with mydomain.com/[folder], it will interfere with the RewriteRule! The folder must not exist in order to load info.php.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73086/discussion-between-anubhava-and-theflarenet).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want an .htaccess to prevent access to /js/, /css/, and /images/ folders. Assuming these are found in the root. Just create an .htaccess file in each folder with the following code:

```
deny from all
```

This was taken from:

[deny direct access to a folder and file by htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282124/deny-direct-access-to-a-folder-and-file-by-htaccess)

Comment: You are correct however my last RewriteRule seems to still function by loading my index.php thinking the prevented folders are _GET['id'] variables. This solution did not work for me. :-(

Comment: I hope to clarify my answer. Delete the current .htaccess file and create 3 individual .htaccess files in the folders:  /js/, /css/, and /images/ .

Then you could access your root files but prevent access to the other files. And by default apache will prevent any higher access.

Comment: If I do that, I lose my rewrite to mydomain.com/[idvariable]