# How can I stop direct access of a folder with Apache using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web

I have tried to use

> deny from all

So it blocks the whole contains and can be access by the page also..

Comment: `Deny from all` did not work?  Could you be more clear? You want to deny access but you *also* want to allow access somehow?

Comment: You can use `robot.txt` too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deny direct access to a folder and file by htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282124/deny-direct-access-to-a-folder-and-file-by-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to deny access to the folder:

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/folder/?$
```

just replace **folder** with name of the folder you want to deny access to.

To deny access to folder and files

You can use :

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/folder/.+$
```

This will show forbidden error for the folder and files.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a blank index.html file and upload it to each folder. It's easier and safer..

Answer (score 0):

Deny from all

Allow from all

This code is working under .htaccess to solve the above problem

Thanks guys for help...