# deny access to directory listing using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, security, laravel-5

I want to deny access to particular directory to show list of files in it in the browser. For example, If I go to the url, localhost/myproject/assets, it will show all the list of files in it, I want to deny that. And also if logged in user access specific file in it, for ex : localhost/myproject/assets/uploads/img/1.jpg then it should be accessible. 
Also how to deny access to a localhost/myproject/assets/uploads/img/1.jpg if that 1.jpg is uploaded by some other user.

I'm new to laravel ,Any help is much appreciated. thanks

Comment: Which web server are you running your app with? It would also be helpful to see you web servers configuration file.

Comment: Using Apache webserver.

Comment: About your last question: You can't, at least not when you place the files in a directory that is publicly accessible through the web-server. The only way to achieve that is to move the files to a place that is not accessible and serve them through php.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the following to the .htaccess file in the folder. This might help.

```
Options -Indexes
```

You cannot deny the access to the jpg uploaded by another user.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Apache, you can place a .htaccess file in the folder you want to block. Then you can use `deny from all` to block all requests to that folder.

This works because a .htaccess file can be in every directory in your web root, and only cares about the directory it is in and its subdirectories.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9282193/4285005).