# PHP directly accessing the required files

Tags: php, file, include, require

So I work on a website and to make things easier I made specific files for every task (like: for the top menu I made `menu.php`) and then `require();` them in the main files. All is good but I tried accessing in the browser `/include/menu.php` and it shows up. I don't want people to access them whenever they want, I just want to require them and to be available only through the main file.

Comment: Take a look at htaccess

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to prevent other php files from being accessed, is to define a variable in the main script:

```
define('IN_APPLICATION', true);
```

In all of your other files, simply add:

```
if ( !defined('IN_APPLICATION') )
    die('You cannot access this file directly.');
```

An alternative way is to use an [`.htaccess` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9282193/4875631). If your server is running apache, this is all you will need. Simply put this file in your `/includes` directory.

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that. I simply made an $onSamePage = 1; variable on the main page and check if it's true on the included one.