# Stopping direct file access using URL

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I am using laravel,
In browser If I directly give the URL as below :

```
http://....../resources/views/users/index.blade.php
```

It will show the page as below :

[image]
.

I can't show page to public as above image.

How can I block access to particular folder or files ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit/create `.htaccess` file of the directory you want to prevent the direct access from people.

As per the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282124/deny-direct-access-to-a-folder-and-file-by-htaccess) :

**Solutions - 1**

> I would just move the includes folder out of the web-root, but if you want to block direct access to the whole includes folder, you can put a .htaccess file in that folder that contains just:
>
> ```
> deny from all
> ```
>
> That way you cannot open any file from that folder, but you can
>   include them in php without any problems.

**Solution - 2**

> It's possible to use a Files directive and disallow access to all
>   files, then use it again to set the files that are accessible:
>
> ```
> <Files ~ "^.*">
>   Deny from all
> </Files>
>
> <Files ~ "^index\.php|css|js|.*\.png|.*\.jpg|.*\.gif">
>   Allow from all
> </Files>
> ```

Also, You can Refer to Article : [How to Prevent a Directory Listing of Your Website with .htaccess](https://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/prevent-directory-listing-htaccess.shtml)

Comment: Thank you LuFFy, i use this but it restricts all the folders.

Comment: @baburaj, You have to specify the path if you want to restrict certain folder.