# How to stop direct access to a specific folder?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a folder in my website that is a kind of service. Other pages get data from this folder php files with ajax.

Now I don't want direct access to this folder or php files in this folder

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried searching the web for something like "disallow folder access [INSERTHENAMEOFYOURWEBSERVERHERE]" ?!

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282124/deny-direct-access-to-a-folder-and-file-by-htaccess

Comment: Do you have cPanel?

Comment: Right now I'm testing the application in my pc localhost but I want to upload the project to the host that has cPanel in the next few days

Comment: Any folder that you don't want direct access via the web then keep it outside of `document_root`.

Comment: Then Can ajax use them?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly. you just want to deny access to the some folders?

You can put a .htaccess file in that folder that contains just:

```
deny from all
```

That way you cannot open any file from that folder, but you can include them in php without any problems.