# How to store a file in a Wordpress Plugin without exposing it online?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-calendar-api, wordpress-rest-api

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin that talks to the Google Calendar API through a Google Service Account.

Such a service account comes with a JSON file, which holds its OAuth2 credentials (`client_id`, `public key` & `private key` for example).

For the plugin to work for others, I need them to upload their own JSON credentials file within the plugin. This way the plugin will be able to talk to the Google API and access/modify their personal calendars.

**Here's the thing:**

Wordpress plugin files have no protection, they are publicly accessible. How do I store a JSON file within a plugin, without exposing the credentials it contains?

> "Hey man, you can save JSON in the database..."

I know, but Google's API client requires a string to the credential file, instead of straight JSON:

```
$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('./credentials.json');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [deny direct access to a folder and file by htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282124/deny-direct-access-to-a-folder-and-file-by-htaccess)

Comment: Also, does it need to be a JSON _file_? Can you instead just store those parameters in the database, either as individual fields or as a JSON blob, and supply that to your code?

Comment: @disinfor Not all users of the plugin will host their Wordpress site on Apache, so modifying .htaccess isn't the solution here, but I appriciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be super well documented by Google, but it looks like `setAuthConfig` can also take an array instead of a string. So you should be able to allow the user to store the JSON in the database, then `json_decode` it yourself and pass that to `setAuthConfig`.

```php
// retrieve $jsonString from database somehow
$configArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$client->setAuthConfig($configArray);
```

Note that `json_decode` needs that second parameter set to `true`, so that it decodes as an associative array, which is what the Google library wants.

(and if you're curious, you can see the `setAuthConfig` code here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/81696e6206322e38c643cfcc96c4494ccfef8a32/src/Client.php#L956 Notice how it checks that `$config` is a string, and if it isn't, it just uses it directly. Also, the comment above the function mentions that $config can be an array.)

Comment: To the OP, please do this instead of writing to the file system. Otherwise, if you have just a single client using this plugin, you might be okay because you can hopefully control the file system. But not everyone hosts on Apache and can't therefore use `htaccess` to prevent access to things.

Comment: Didn't notice it myself, thanks! Will use this solution.